# Spacing between column div in looping

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap and I use foreach looping to display products. And the result is as shown below. I want to increase the 'D' box so that the distance with the 'B' box increases like a dotted line illustration. Basically, the fourth cell, D, should align with the third cell, C, vertically as well as horizontally with the second, B. How?

Result:

[image: Illustration with a red dotted line]

Script:

```html
<?php foreach ($produk as $p) : ?>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2">
        <div class="card shadow-sm border-0 mb-4">
            <div class="card-body">
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-link p-0"><i class="material-icons md-18">favorite_outline</i></button>
                
                <figure class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/<?php echo $p['gambar'] ?>" alt="" class=""></figure>
                <a href="product-details.html" class="text-dark mb-1 mt-2 h6 d-block"><?php echo $p['nama_menu'] ?></a>
                <p class="text-secondary small mb-2"><?php echo $p['nama_resto'] ?></p>
                <h5 class="text-success font-weight-normal mb-0">Rp <?php echo substr($p['harga'], 0, -3) ?><sup>.<?php echo substr($p['harga'], -3) ?></sup></h5>
                <p class="text-secondary small text-mute mb-0"> </p>
                <button class="btn btn-default button-rounded-36 shadow-sm float-bottom-right"><i class="material-icons md-18">shopping_cart</i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Can you share your CSS code as well?

Comment: @kks21199 hi, the css i am using bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap 4 you can achieve what you want by using the flex properties.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/

Just put them in a flex-row and then use the correct flex property to make them grow by the biggest one.